# no characters are displayed in the menu of gvim81

Tags: vim, character-encoding, windows-10, menubar

Installation of gvim on windows 10, no characters are displayed in the menubar.

after start screenshot:

[image: after start screenshot]

start menu screenshot:

[image: start menu screenshot]

What should I do?

Comment: what locale are you using on what system?

Answer (score 0):

[Christian Brabandt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/789222/christian-brabandt)
Thank you for hint, [English locale](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ug8Q.png) it's help me ...[English menu-bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CfW1b.jpg)